# Bash command to compress folder(s) with a password

Tags: bash, passwords, zip, gzip

How can I compress two folders into archive file (zip, gzip or something like that) with a password on the files?

For example I have folder structure:

- rootDir

  - dir1
  - dir2
  - dir3
  - dir4

I need bash command to add dir2 and dir4 to same archive file compressed with a password on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
zip -er filename.zip dir2 dir4
```

The `zip` command is widely available; if not on your system, look for a `zip` package or similar.

The `-e` flag specifies encryption is to be used on the zipfile; you'll be prompted for a password.

The `-r` flag specifies recursion; all the files in `dir2` and `dir4` will be included.

The resulting zipped, encrypted file containing `dir2` and `dir4` will be placed at `filename.zip`.

Comment: This is good, how do I do it for all folders , files and subfolders (recursive) ? And another question, how do I provide password without prompt ?

Comment: so the answer I was looking for is: zip -rP "password" filename.zip dir2 dir4

Comment: Note however, that `zip`'s built-in encryption is fairly insecure: http://math.ucr.edu/~mike/zipattacks.pdf . If you want more than protection from casual peeping, use a real encryption software (such as GnuPG or TrueCrypt).

Answer (score 0):

Compress with your favorite unix command (mine is '`tar cfj`' for a BZip2 tarball).
Then [encrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) with [`bcrypt`](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/).

> **Bcrypt** is a cross platform file encryption utility.

But, they say bcrypt is no longer safe (! [`;-)`](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/03/blowfish_on_24_1.html)),
Well, change to [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq) (it too is cross platform -- [easycrypt](http://ubuntuguru.wordpress.com/2007/12/01/how-to-keep-secret-with-easy-crypt/)).

Tip: Encryption *after* compression makes life much more interesting.

Comment: what do you mean by "more interesting"?

Comment: This approach is interesting, as it will hide the file list in the compressed file, unlike zipped file.